# A finite $k$-scheme which is proper but not projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be a $k$-scheme. It is a fact that $X$ is finite (over $k$) if and only if it is both affine and proper (over $k$) (see e.g. Corollary 12.89 in Gortz Wedhorn). I wonder whether "proper" can be replaced by "projective." In other words, does there exist a finite $k$-scheme which is proper but not projective?

A finite $k$-scheme is the spectrum of a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite morphism is projective, see [the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B3I).